# Meromorphic continuation of an integral similar to Tate integral

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, measure-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $\phi(s,z)$ denote a complex valued function on $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{R}^*$ which is Schwartz function on $z$ for every fixed $s$ and holomorphic function on $s$ for every fixed $z$. Then does the following integral have a meromorphic continuation to the entire complex plane:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^*}\phi(s,z)|z|^s d^*z$$

Any help is deeply appreciated.